# React BigCalendar - all events in a different color

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, react-big-calendar

As the title states I am trying make all events in my react-bigCalendar have different colors and I have tried different methods and read different answer. I cannot seem to get it to work and wrap my head around it.
My `eventPropGetter` looks like the following but `const backgroundColor = meetingRoom ? meetingRoom.color : "#fff";` returns undefined.

The full code of the bigCalendar component:

```
          <Calendar
                components={toolBarButtonActions()}
                defaultView='week'
                localizer={localizer}
                events={roomEvents}
                startAccessor="start"
                endAccessor="end"
                style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%", margin: "55px" }}
                eventPropGetter={event => {
                    const meetingRoom = rooms.filter(room => room.id === event.locationId)[0];
                    const backgroundColor = meetingRoom ? meetingRoom.color : "#fff"; //is undefined in chromeDevTools
                    return { style: { backgroundColor } };
                }}
             />
```

If anyone has any input it would be helpful.

Comment: You need to provide more details here. What does `roomEvents` looks like? Sample sandbox to test?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// assuming 'rooms' memoized
const eventPropGetter = useCallback(({locationId}) => {
  // don't assume you have the 'room'
  const {color: backgroundColor} = rooms.find(({id}) => id === locationId) ?? {};
  // return it if you have it
  return {
    ...(backgroundColor && {style: {backgroundColor}})
  };
}, [rooms]);

<Calendar
  {...otherProps}
  eventPropGetter={eventPropGetter}
/>
```